# How does a function that returns a function work?

Tags: swift, function

I'm reading Apple's book about Swift and stumbled upon this piece of code, which I after many tries couldn't understand. As far as I understand, this function returns a function. The two last lines of code, as well as all the code, though, are totally bewildering. And how we can assign a function to a variable (the seventh line)? Thank you.

I've typed it myself into the Playground but still don't get it.

```
func makeIncrement () -> ((Int) -> Int){
    func addOne (number: Int) -> Int{
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrement()
increment(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be considered objects in Swift (or as first class functions - worth researching).
Therefore may be assigned to variables and to object properties.

So in your code `makeIncrement` simply returns the function `addOne` as a variable.

`var increment = makeIncrement()` can just be seen as assigning the returned function from `makeIncrement` as a variable (or function object) `increment`.

We can then freely call the `increment` function as we would call `addOne`or any other function really.

Comment: Oh, so after `var increment = makeIncrement()` my variable `increment` actually contains the `addOne` function, am I right?

Comment: @YaroslavHrytsun, you are right.  Note that since `makeIncrement()` returns the `addOne` function, you can even call it immediately instead of assigning it to a variable like this: `makeIncrement()(7)`

Answer (score 0):

A function is something with optional input and a return type. If you alt-click on the var `increment` you will see that increment is of type `((Int) -> Int)`. This means that you can input an `Int` and will return an `Int`. This is then done in the last line by calling this function.

If you know object-oriented programming, you will know that you can always pass objects around, which also have functions. In this way, in your code, it is doing the same but now we are omitting the object.